# Ways to get last commit author in Github Actions workflow

Tags: github, github-actions

I am working on converting a Jenkins Pipeline into a Github Actions workflow and need a way of storing the commit author as an environment variable for later use in node.js code.

I have read the documentation and this seems to be the only way I can get it working:

```
name: Feature Branch PR

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited, synchronize]
  push:
    branches: 
    - '**'
```

Then in the Env section:

```
env:
   AUTHOR: ${{ github.event.pusher.name }}
```

The problem is this only works for Push triggers. So if i remove the on: push section from top of yml workflow (so it only triggers on PRs) the AUTHOR info becomes empty.

I cannot find a way to get it for commits. Does anyone know of of a way? We do not want this workflow to trigger on pushes.

I also tried

```
        AUTHOR: $(jq '.commits.committer.name' $GITHUB_EVENT_PATH)
```

I think this was syntactically incorrect though.

Comment: For anyone looking for a quick answer: Use `${GITHUB_ACTOR} <${GITHUB_ACTOR}@users.noreply.github.com>` as your author. GITHUB_ACTOR is the person that caused the workflow to run.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone who struggles with this in future, I managed to work it out.

In the node code (not yml) you can obtain an Actions event.json file with all info available. To get the author of a previous commit:

```
 const ev = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.GITHUB_EVENT_PATH, 'utf8'));
  return ev.pull_request.user.login;
```

Comment: have you tried `${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}`?

Answer (score 3):

As [YakovL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3995261/yakovl) mentioned,

```
env:
  ${{ github.event.pull_request.user.login }}
```

Works fine in a Github action.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question that was originally asked, you can do the following to get the author of the last commit in a GitHub action:

`github.event.commits[0].author.name`

For example (to prevent a loop in an action using a personal access token):

```
name: Version and Package Repo
on:
  push:
    branches: [ master, main ]
jobs:
  build:
    if: github.event.commits[0].author.name != 'GitHubActions'
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
    - name: Checkout repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0
        token: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
    - name: Configure git
      run: |
        git config user.name "GitHubActions"
        git config user.email "<>"
    - name: Version and Package
      run: npm version patch --force
      env:
        NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: $\{{ secrets.PAT }}
    - name: Update git
      run: |
        git push
        git push --tags
```

You can use this in the interpolation format too:

`${github.event.commits[0].author.name}`

And if you need to use different github context variables, they are documented at:

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push

Annoyingly, the user details are in different formats for different event types, but in addition to example above (for push), you could try `github.event.head.user.login` or `github.event.base.user.login` too

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can do the following to get the author of the last commit in a GitHub action:

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  retrieve-commit-author:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Get commit author's username
        run: |
          COMMIT_AUTHOR=$(git log -1 --pretty=%an)
          echo "Commit author: $COMMIT_AUTHOR"
```

In this script, the `%an` placeholder is used to get the author's name from the commit.